# How to have length constrained std::string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, size, string-length

I would like to have a `std::string` like class (say, `string_n`) such that objects of `string_n` cannot be more than `N` chars long.

`N` may be specified at compile time. An attempt to create `string_n` of larger length may assert or throw an exception.

One option is something like following but it would **miss** all the nice member functions offered by `std::string`.

```
template <size_t N>
class string_n {
  char char_[N + 1];
};
```

Another option is to roll out a new class like the following.

```
template <size_t N>
class string_n {
  public:
    // constructor and assignment operators with length check

    ~string_n() = default;

    // for readers
    const string& get() const;

  private:
    std::string string_;
};
```

This would require a lot of boilerplate code.

I have a feeling that there might be a better approach. What would you suggest?

Comment: I suggest redoing the interface of `std::string`. The main reason is that by using `std::string` you will loose the benefit of no allocations, which fixed size strings give you.

Comment: @SergeyA: `std::string::reserve` ... okay so it's one rather than zero but c'mon :P

Comment: @Arun I'm not sure what you mean by boilerplate code... if you want "all the nice member functions offered by `std::string`," then you're going to have to reimplement them or extend string and override each member function that could increase the string size, checking for whether it goes beyond your specified limit.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, reserve is still an allocation. As well as constructing the string, copying larger string to shorter one (when short-string optimization is on), etc. There is a strong support for no-allocation systems.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible or not but you might be able to use a custom allocator and `std::basic_string`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Not really. The container controls when allocations happen and how big they are. So even if your specialized allocator wants to allocate only once, the container can make it allocate more than once. And even if your allocator makes the allocation big enough to handle `N` chars, `basic_string` will assume that it's only as big as it asked for. So when it needs more than that, it will ask for a new allocation. And containers/allocators don't have a way to ask for a `realloc` equivalent; it's always "new block + copy/move".

Comment: @NicolBolas I figured something like that was going to come up.  I just wasn't sure(I have not used custom allocators yet) so I wanted to through the idea out there.

Comment: I would use `std::array<char, N>` since `std::string` resembles standard containers.

Comment: @nimble_ninja: I meant all the member functions string manipulating (e.g. insert, append, erase, replace) member functions of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

This gets close:

```
template<size_t N, class CharT, class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>>
struct basic_string_n:
  std::array<CharT, N>,
  std::experimental::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>
{
  using storage = std::array<CharT, N>;
  using access = std::experimental::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>;
  using storage::operator[];
  using storage::data;
  using access::size;

  basic_string_n(basic_string_n const& o):
    storage(o),
    access(regen(*this))
  {}
  basic_string_n& operator=(basic_string_n const& o)
  {
    *this = (storage const&)o;
    *this = regen(*this);
    return *this;
  }
  void remove_prefix(std::size_t n) = delete;
  void remove_suffix(std::size_t n) = delete;
  void swap( basic_string_n& other ) {
    using std::swap;
    swap( (storage&)*this, (storage&)other );
    *this = regen(*this);
    other = regen(other);
  }
private:
  friend access regen(storage& self) {
    return {self.data(), CharT::length(self.data())};
  }
};
```

here we mix an array of characters with a `std::experimental::basic_string_view`.  What is missing are operations to add or remove characters.

Answer (score 1):

that's my poor approach based on other answers, did it a couple weeks ago:
https://gist.github.com/digitalist/a48a9a7edd5a105bafe5

uses a custom allocators, there are links to stackoverflow answers in the source.

I'm still learning C++ and hints are very welcome, I'll need to use this gist later